# Optimization of a custom function with 2 outputs in R

Tags: r, optimization

I am fairly new to R but I have been writing complex macros in Excel for a long time.  Lately, those macros have been taking a long time to run so I am trying to convert to R.  The function below receives 5 weights as input and returns two values as output.  I am trying to find the inputs so that, for each value of one of the outputs, the other output is maximized.  When I type `optim(par=c(.5,.5,.5,.5,.5), dataGetter, gr=NULL)` it gives me an error that I assume to be the result of having two outputs. Is there a way to specify the value of one of the outputs (hold it constant) and use `optim()` to maximize the other one?

```
dataGetter <- function( hedgeWeights ) {
    spotData        <- read.csv("RtestSpots.csv")
    fwdData         <- read.csv("RtestFWDs.csv")
    notionals       <- c(341538461.54, 46153846.15, 32307692.31, 
                         27692307.69, 13846153.85)
    currentFWDs     <- (fwdData[nrow(fwdData),] -
                        spotData[nrow(spotData), 2:6]) / 
                        spotData[nrow(spotData), 2:6]
    #hedgeWeights   <- c(.4, .4, .4, .4, .4)
    unhedgedWeights <- 1 - hedgeWeights

    returns <- getReturn(spotData[c("Date","EURUSD")],18, "EURUSD")
    returns <- cbind(returns, getReturn(spotData[c("Date","USDJPY")], 
                     18, "USDJPY"))
    returns <- cbind(returns, getReturn(spotData[c("Date","USDCAD")], 
                     18, "USDCAD"))
    returns <- cbind(returns, getReturn(spotData[1:(nrow(spotData)-8), 
                     c("Date","USDMXN")],10, "USDMXN")                )
    returns <- cbind(returns, getReturn(spotData[1:(nrow(spotData)-8), 
                                       c("Date","AUDUSD")], 10, "AUDUSD"))
    cost    <- hedgeWeights * currentFWDs*notionals
    returnAmounts <- t(notionals*t(returns)*unhedgedWeights)
    returnAmounts <- cbind(returnAmounts, rowSums(returnAmounts))
    colnames(returnAmounts)[6] <- c("Total")
    returnAmounts <- cbind(returnAmounts, abs(returnAmounts[,c("Total")]))
    colnames(returnAmounts)[7] <- c("Absolute")
    EURpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("EURUSD")], c(.05, .95))
    JPYpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("USDJPY")], c(.05, .95))
    CADpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("USDCAD")], c(.05, .95))
    MXNpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("USDMXN")], c(.05, .95))
    AUDpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("AUDUSD")], c(.05, .95))
    TOTpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("Total")], c(.05, .95))
    ABSpercentile <- quantile(returnAmounts[,c("Absolute")], c(.05, .95))
    #print(returnAmounts)
    #print(list(colMeans(returnAmounts), EURUSD=EURpercentile, 
    #      USDJPY=JPYpercentile,         USDCAD=CADpercentile, 
    #      USDMXN=MXNpercentile,         AUDUSD=AUDpercentile, 
    #      Total=TOTpercentile, Absolute=ABSpercentile))
    return(list(Risk=TOTpercentile, Cost=sum(cost)))
}
```

Here's the second function:

```
getReturn <- function(data, months, CCY) {
    #Assumes 'data' is a two-column data frame with date in the first 
    #  column, price in the second

    num.rows <- nrow(data)
    #num.cols <- ncol(data)

    output.range <- 1:(num.rows-(months+1))

    buy.price  <- data[output.range,2]
    sell.price <- data[output.range+months,2]

    returns         <- data.frame((sell.price - buy.price)/buy.price)
    #returns        <- cbind(data[output.range,],returns)
    #names(returns) <- c("Date","Price","Return")
    names(returns)  <- c(CCY)

    return(returns)
}
```

Comment: That's great!. But you're gonna have to dumb it down for us. Think of us as programmers. We don't really know what a forward is. It's better if you tell us that it is a vector, or a matrix, etc.

Comment: hmmmmmm...The function receives a vector of weights and then imports two files with prices.  It uses the prices and the vector of weights to return a 5th percentile worst outcome over time and the cost of that outcome.  I want to be able to tell R what the 5th percentile outcome should be and have it maximize the cost by changing the input vector.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the whole thing, which is why I'm not answering yet. A few recommendations. You might want to check the zoo package to calculate those returns. I think the name of the function is 'rollapply'. It will calculate a rolling window of returns for you.

Comment: The function works fine.  It returns the cost of the hedge and 5th percentile worst outcome for a given set of weights.  Now I want to optimize those weights.

Comment: You're not really asking an R question then?  You're really looking for how to optimize the weights?

Comment: I am asking how to use R to optimize the weights.  If I had written this function in VBA, I would send it throug a macro that I wrote that basically calls Solver() a bunch of times to optimize the weights.  Maybe I am not asking the question correctly.  I wrote a function in R.  I need to figure out the best combination of inputs that maximize one of the outputs while holding the other constant.

Comment: See here's the thing.  You should come to SO when you know what you want to do but not how to do it programmatically. If you could give us a formula or algorithm for what you wanted then we could help you.  What you're asking is not a programming question.

Comment: ok, the function above returns two parameters.  Call them X and Y.  When I write:

        optim(par=c(.5,.5,.5,.5,.5), dataGetter, gr=NULL)

It gives me an error that I assume to be the result of having two outputs.  Is there a way to specifiy the value of one of the outputs (hold it constant) and use optim() to maximize the other one?

Comment: @user3390169 these details about what you've tried and what problems you're having are exactly what you should include in your post. Please update your post to describe your attempts so far with the `optim` function.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName, I think you're being a bit hard on a first-time SO user. Once the OP updates the question to describe his/her previous attempts with the `optim` function, I would consider this a fine question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you formulated it, is as follows:
you have two functions, `f` and `g`,
and you want to find the argument `p`
that maximizes `f(p)` subject 
to the condition `g(p)=q` (for various values of `q`).

That is a constrained optimization problem:
you can look at the `Rsolnp` or `alabama` packages.
Alternatively, you can convert the constraints into penalties,
and maximize `f(p) - A*(g(p)-q)^2` for increasing values of `A`
with `optim` or any other non-constrained optimizer.

However, since you are apparently computing an efficient frontier,
you can simply maximize `f(p) - A * g(p)`, for various values of `A`:
each value of `A` will give a point on the efficient frontier.
That is usually easier, faster, and more accurate.